# Rich Text Control on a Layouts Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-controls

I want to create and deploy a layouts page in a SharePoint 2013 environment. It is basically a form where you can store values.

Is it possible to use the Rich Text Control which is utilizing the ribbon for formatting?

**Edit1**
[image: I want this control] 
**
     I want the control "Multi" as seen on the picture.

Comment: I see, yeah just steal the code from a page that uses that then. (I do this to get around EVERY problem that I can't do OOTB easily :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer:
Steal it from a working one on a page OOTB using ILSpy. (Answer to everything)

Wrong answer but left in: This is the 2007 control
This is how the control should look Max:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox
    runat="server"
    ID="RichTextBox"
    ValidationGroup="foo" 
    Rows="10" 
    Columns="50" 
    TextMode="MultiLine" 
    RichText="true" 
    RichTextMode="FullHtml" 
    AllowHyperlink="true" />
```

Comment: Apparently this results in the retro control with the toolbar above the control - no ribbon yet.

Comment: Sorry max, misunderstood, you want to basically grab and steal the content editor web part (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart for this. Pretty easy to do infact someone has already done it for you. http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/develop-custom-editable-visual-web-part.html